# Any Alternative for Power tools in TFS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, vs-extensibility

I need custom fields in TFS2017. I found Power tools[vsix] extension does the purpose in TFS 2013.

I've tried Productivity PowerPack which is somewhat equivalent to Power Tools.
On Installation i've got the following error

> TFS Power tools for 2017. TFS Process Template Editor & ProductivityPowerPack2017 is not supported by Visual studio 2017 IDE (enterprise edition)
>   Found installed product - Visual Studio Build Tools 2017

IS there any alternative for Power tools for TFS 2017, purpose is to create custom fields in work Items. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to install the extension [TFS Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor) for VS 2017.

Comment: Perfect. Any diff between Power Tools Extension and this TFS Process Template Editor?